# Large sieve inequality-like sum without the square

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, exponential-sums, sieve-theory

Let $S(\alpha) = \sum_{n\leq N} w(n) e^{2\pi i \alpha n}$ for some function $w$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_R$ are real numbers that are $\delta$-spaced modulo $1$, for some $0 < \delta < 1/2$. The large sieve inequality then gives
$$
\sum_{r=1}^R \left| S\left(\alpha_r \right)\right|^2 \ll (N + \delta^{-1}) \sum_{n\leq N}|w(n)|^2.
$$

I am trying to obtain as good as possible pound to a sum that looks like
$$
\sum_{r=1}^R \left| S\left(\alpha_r \right)\right|,
$$
that is like the sum in the large sieve but without the squares. Of course one can use Cauchy-Schwarz and apply the large sieve
$$
\sum_{r=1}^R \left| S\left(\alpha_r \right)\right| \ll \sqrt{R}  (\sum_{r=1}^R \left| S\left(\alpha_r \right)\right|^2)^{1/2} \ll \sqrt{R (N + \delta^{-1})} (\sum_{n\leq N}|w(n)|^2)^{1/2}.
$$
Since this was not giving me the upperbound I was hoping for, if someone could suggest me any other alternative approaches that could be useful, it'd be appreciated!

Comment: For $N\gg\delta^{-1}$, if one takes $w(n)$ iid random variables with $\mathbb P(w(n) = \pm 1) = 1/2$ for each choice of sign, then it can be shown with Khintchine's inequality that what you get from Cauchy-Schwarz is sharp on average. What sort of upper bound are you hoping for?